# Why did Bush enact a completely different foreign policy to that which he espoused during the 2000 Presidential election campaign?

Tags: united-states, foreign-policy, george-w-bush

I was watching a [campaign video from 2000](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsvf1HU0KHM), in it Bush clearly thinks the USA's position as the 'world police' or that their foreign intervention strategy, especially ones that instill virtues on other sovereign states, are ill advised.

How is this reconciled with many choices he made as president, namely the Iraq war? Why did he change his tune?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would like to point out that while Bush himself did make such statements, many of the key figures in his cabinet made completely opposite statements.

10 of his cabinet members, including central ones such as Dick Cheney, Donald Rumsfeld, and Paul Wolfowitz, were signatories to the mission statement of a think-tank called [The Project for a New American Century.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_for_the_New_American_Century)  This group had 25 signatories in total.

PNAC's stated goal was "to promote American global leadership." The organization stated that "American leadership is good both for America and for the world," and sought to build support for "a Reaganite policy of military strength and moral clarity."

Observers such as [Irwin Stelzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin_Stelzer) and [David Grondin](https://en.com.umontreal.ca/repertoire-departement/vue/grondin-david/) have suggested that the PNAC played a key role in shaping the foreign policy of the Bush Administration, particularly in building support for the Iraq War.

Key PNAC members had been advocating regime change in Iraq since 1998.

One particular publication by PNAC which is discussed frequently is [Rebuilding America's Defenses: Strategy, Forces and Resources For a New Century](http://web.archive.org/web/20020206003030/http://www.newamericancentury.org/RebuildingAmericasDefenses.pdf), **published in September 2000.** Here are some quotes from it which I consider signifigant:

> The immediate task is to rebuild today's force, ensuring that it is
>   equal to the tasks before it: shaping the peacetime environment and
>   **winning multiple, simultaneous theater wars;** these forces must be
>   large enough to accomplish these tasks without running the “high” or
>   “unacceptable” risks it faces now.

---

> None  of the defense reviews of the past  decade has weighed fully 
>   the  range of missions demanded by  U.S. global leadership:  defending
>   the  homeland, **fighting  and winning  multiple large-scale wars,
>   conducting constabulary missions** which preserve  the current  peace,
>   and transforming  the U.S. armed forces to exploit  the “revolution 
>   in military  affairs.”

---

> Further, the process  of transformation, even  if  it  brings 
>   revolutionary change,  is likely  to be  a  long  one, absent  **some
>   catastrophic  and catalyzing  event – like a new Pearl Harbor.**

Emphasis mine. I do not mean to imply anything by the last quote. Being one of the more famous quotes from the document, however, I felt I had to include it.

I'd also like to point out that politicians do not always mean what they say, both during campaigns, elections, and their terms in office.

Whether or not Bush truly did agree with the sentiments of PNAC before 9/11, the fact that he selected so many of its signatories for his cabinet is, in my opinion, more of a political statement than anything he *said* during his campaign. Actions speak louder than words. To give Bush the benefit of the doubt, it's possible that he simply did not know his cabinet members very well. That would be grossly incompetent, which is certainly possible. I do not speculate on his personal character or motives.

Sources for claims about PNAC are in their own mission statement, and in the sources of the Wikipedia article on PNAC. Two sentences in this answer have been copied verbatim from Wikipedia.

Comment: “Observers such as Irwin Stelzer and Dave Grondin” - who are they?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Irwin M. Stelzer is an American economist who is the U.S. economic and business columnist for The Sunday Times in the United Kingdom and The Courier-Mail in Australia. In the United States, he has been a contributing editor at The Weekly Standard. David Grondin is an associate professor at the University of Montreal who has published papers on the topic in with The International Centre for Comparative Criminology (ICCC).

Comment: This reads like a conspiracy theory.

Comment: @Sjoerd While there is nothing wrong with conspiracy theories (people in power have **conspired** to do immoral or illegal things since the dawn of civilization, and **theories** are essential to scientific thought), which theory do you feel I am propagating here? I do not see that this answer is making any claims, other than those I have cited sources for, such as the mission statement of PNAC, etc. I have explicitly made no speculative claims in this answer.

Comment: @Sjoerd This answer states that Bush selected people for his cabinet that had explicitly stated that they supported an interventionist foreign policy, which was at odds with his campaign rhetoric. That may fit the description of a conspiracy, as it may be deceptive to the voters. It is indeed also a theory, but I consider it supported by evidence, as those cabinet members had explicitly signed a mission statement. This answer does not make any other allegations.

Comment: @Sjoerd Also, I'm puzzled how this term "conspiracy theory" can be thrown around, as if it's a logical argument. Bush lying about WMDs was a CT before it turned out to be correct. Watergate was a CT. Enron was. So I don't see why it's even relevant to note that something is a CT. If some theory appears false, one can take apart its arguments and evidence, or provide evidence to the contrary. Using a term like CT would appear to me to be a logical fallacy.

Comment: @Revetahw - It seems to be a gross misuse of the phrase "conspiracy theory". After all, American criminal law is explicit about "conspiracy to committ murder", recognizing that conspiracies exist and have real effects. "Conspiracy theories" seek to explain most or all social facts through conspiratory plots. In that sense, there is nothing CT-ish in your answer. Bush conspired to get elected by lying about his foreign policies? Perfectly possible. That lie was a consequence of the Jewish/Freemason/Lizardian secret cabal that rules the world? No, that's false, and it is a conspiracy theory.

Comment: @LuísHenrique Thanks for your comment. If I understand you correctly, are you making a distinction between theories that are backed up by evidence (such as Iran Contra) and those that are not (subterranean lizards secretly rule the world) and saying that those backed up by evidence should not be called conspiracy theories, while the unfounded ones should?

Comment: @Revetahw - part of it is a question of evidence, but there is another aspect. I may believe, without evidence, or on flimsy evidence, that, for instance, the *Maine* was deliberately sunk as part of a false flag operation. This, even if false or unsupported by evidence, is not a conspiracy theory; it is just a more, or less, justifiable belief about one historical fact. An actual conspiratory theory is totalising; it does not seek to explain one historical fact, but the whole of human history, and that by the agency of a small group of conspirators.

Comment: For instance, if someone says that Bush lied about his foreign policy in order to get elected, this isn't a conspiracy theory; if someone says that Bush lied about his foreign policy because Skull and Bones secretely directs both American foreign policy and Al Qaida actions, and wanted a war that could be framed as defensive... then we are in the territory of conspiracy theories.

Comment: @LuísHenrique I see. That is an interesting way to look at it, one which I have never considered. Regarding the "totalising" aspect though, what if I allege (hypothetically, this is just an example for the purpose of discussing definitions) that the 7/7 bombings in London were secretly orchestrated by Tony Blair and some MI6 guys because Blair wanted continued support for his foreign wars. Let us say I did not allege that this was because Blair was part of a secret international cabal, etc,  but had simple political motives. Would that then **not** be  a CT, due to the "totalising" aspect?

Comment: @Revetahw - in and of itself, perhaps not. But it isn't likely that one would believe that Blair orchestrated the 7/7 attacks without believing several other things, which, all summed, are probably withing the scope of conspiracy theories (the Tories had no inside information from the MI6? how that?). Further, the totalising aspect generally involves the "reasoning" that the absence of evidence is a proof that evidence has been suppressed, which requires some kind of overarching cabal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90987/discussion-between-revetahw-and-luis-henrique).

Answer (score 15):

Sept. 11 changed everything. It demonstrated with the utmost clarity the risks of an unpoliced world.

The first change was in Afghanistan. The Taliban had largely ruled Afghanistan since about 1996. The US certainly didn't like them, but also didn't view them as America's problem.

On September 11, the NSA and German intelligence both [intercepted communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_for_the_September_11_attacks#Assigning_responsibility) pointing to Bin Laden. Some hijackers were [identified while the planes were still in the air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsibility_for_the_September_11_attacks#Identifying_the_hijackers). Mohamed Atta's luggage, which did not make his flight, was [also helpful](https://www.aviationpros.com/home/news/10400889/luggage-that-didnt-get-put-on-sept-11-jet-provided-lead-to-terrorists).

Already on Semptember 12, many in the US [suspected that he was to blame](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/09/12/us/us-attacked-president-vows-to-exact-punishment-for-evil.html).

It also helped that the hijackers purchased their tickets using their real names. By September 14, the FBI released the [names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_for_September_following_the_September_11_attacks#Friday,_September_14) of the hijackers.

Also on Sept. 14, Congress passed a [law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization_for_Use_of_Military_Force_Against_Terrorists) authorizing the military to attack anyone associated with terrorists. The vote was 98-0 in the Senate and 420-1 in the House.

On Sept. 21, the Taliban [refused a US demand to hand over Bin Laden](https://www.nytimes.com/2001/09/21/world/nation-challenged-taliban-afghans-coaxing-bin-laden-but-us-rejects-clerics-bid.html). For Bush, that was plenty of reason to go to war. The US decision to [overthrow the Taliban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Afghanistan) was supported by [nearly everyone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_public_opinion_on_the_war_in_Afghanistan#International_public_opinion_compared_to_American_public_opinion) in the US.

Then there was Iraq. Although he was not involved in planning them, Saddam Hussein originally [praised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_to_the_September_11_attacks) the attacks. Saddam had used chemical weapons during the war against Iran, and he was [refusing to cooperate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_and_weapons_of_mass_destruction) with inspectors who were supposed to verify that he had given them up. Some people reasoned, wrongly, that if he didn't have anything to hide, he would be cooperating with the inspectors. And Saddam had a [history of supporting terrorists](https://www.cfr.org/backgrounder/iraq-iraqi-ties-terrorism), for example paying $25,000 to the family of every Palestinian suicide bomber.

Based on this, Bush made a [case for war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationale_for_the_Iraq_War) against Saddam. That was hotly debated at the time. Most Republicans were in favor. Some Democrats, such as Hillary Clinton, were also [in favor](https://awpc.cattcenter.iastate.edu/2017/03/09/hillary-clinton-iraq-war-vote-speech-oct-10-2002/), while others, such as Barack Obama, were [opposed](https://thehill.com/blogs/congress-blog/politics/27304-obama-video-showcases-2002-anti-war-speech). United Republican support and mixed Democratic sentiment was enough to get Congress to agree to the invasion.

Comment: Though this answer seems _mostly_ correct, the segue into the Iraq war seems completely wrong. [Other groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_to_the_September_11_attacks#Palestinian_celebrations) that praised the attacks on the WTC and Pentagon were not attacked as was Iraq. There may (or may not) have been reasons for the US to attack Iraq, but praise for 9/11 was not one of them.

Comment: "It demonstrated with the utmost clarity that even if the US were to adopt a policy of nonintervention in the rest of the world" I must have missed the part of the GW Bush presidency when he tried not intervening in the rest of the world..

Comment: @dotancohen My purpose in the answer was not to argue whether or not the invasion was correct. It was to show how 9/11 helped create the support that allowed it to happen.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch while 9/11 as a potential factor in changing his stance is very valid, the first sentence seems like an arbitrary political statement. One could equally say 9/11 proved that US interference, like sponsoring radical rebel groups, will eventually result in backlash. While the general claim is true - non-intervention does not *guarantee* non-intervention by others - the claim that this was proven by 9/11 is ridiculous given the lack of non-intervention politics before that.

Comment: A reasonable point. Edited above.

Answer (score 2):

During his presidential campaign GW Bush promised the kind of foreign policy that (he thought) would **get him elected** in 2000. Subsequently, he enacted a foreign policy that (he thought) would **get him re-elected** in 2004. The striking difference between the two is probably due to changing attitudes of the US electorate after the 9/11 terrorist attacks. One additional explanation of politicians doing different things when in power versus campaign promises is to look for sponsors who the politicians "owe" favours in return for financial support of their campaign.